# Частично отключить логирование при тестах в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, юнит-тесты

Вопрос по тестированию в Ларавел. Есть контроллер, в нем есть логирование при возникновении ошибок. Использую HTTP тестирование. Тестирую разные сценарий в том числе и ошибочные. Естественно в логе тестов появляются сообщения об ошибках.

Собственно вопрос - как в тестах, где я тестирую ошибки отключить логирование? Или вообще в тестах забить на логи, которые я выбрасываю сам?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, у Вас PSR3 логгер. Тогда для тестового окружения подпихните в конфигурацию NullLogger.
В принципе, если нет, но иинъектится интерфейс логгера, то можно реализовать NullLogger самому

Comment: Для всего окружения пропихнуть нул логер проблем нет. Проблема пропихнуть его для определенных тестов.

Comment: Не совсем понял, для чего в некоторых тестах нужен сам логгер. Где логгирование не нужно - NullLogger. Где нужно проверить работу логгера - мок логгера и ассертить его вызовы

Comment: Как можно замокать логер при http тестах?  Да еще который статик вызывается

Comment: https://blog.gougousis.net/mocking-static-methods-with-mockery/

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать в тестах фейковый логер https://github.com/timacdonald/log-fake.